# How to add jss and css in magento2

Tags: magento2, layout, css

I have created a block and called it in my phtml file then I call that block in my cms page like this `{{block class="Abc\Custom\Block\Product" template="Abc_Custom::product.phtml"}}`

and some HTML code in phtml file but I don't have controllers so now how do I add CSS and js file using layout XML

Answer (score 2):

You can add your js and css using layout by below method

Edit your layout file **app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/layout/test_index_index.xml**

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
       <head>
          <css src="css/mycustomcss.css" />
          <script src="js/mycustomjs.js"/>
     </head> 
       <body>
                 //your code here
     </body> 
    </page>
```

Create your js and css file in your module as below path.

```
app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/web/css/mycustomcss.css

app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/web/js/mycustomjs.js
```

Comment: test_index_index.xml i dont want this

Comment: you can replace this with your layout. @sdfasdf

Answer (score 2):

Magento 2 brings some new features in javascript. One of them is “requireJS” (javascript file loader) and second is “jQuery“, a very popular js library. One of the biggest benefits is using requireJS which means that Magento 2 is ready for the upcoming HTTP2 protocol.

1) Place your requirejs-config.js file in one of the following directories (according to the location of your custom script):

Your theme files: `<theme_dir>`
Or
Your module view files: /view/frontend
requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
  "map": {
    "*": {
      "menu": "js/navigation-menu"
    }
  }
};
```

2) Load your js files in your template files

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
  'menu'
  ], function(menu){
  $(document).ready( function() {
    //Do your actions here
});
});
</script>
```

Refer this Magento Dev Docs for more information https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html

For loading CSS, you can directly load it through layout XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
<head>
  <css src="css/mycustomcss.css" />
</head> 
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\layout\default_head_blocks.xml
```

override this (default_head_blocks.xml) xml file in your custom theme like below

```
app\design\frontend\Package\custom-theme\Magento_Theme\layout\default_head_blocks.xml
```

add below code in default_head_blocks.xml file

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="js/custom.css"/> OR <css src="css/custom.less"/>
        <script src="js/custom.js"/>
    </head>

</page>
```

keep your js and css/less file in

```
\app\design\frontend\Package\custom-theme\web\css\custom.css
\app\design\frontend\Package\custom-theme\web\js\custom.js
```

after check your changes.